# Sticky footer works on index page, but stays in the center of all the other pages covering content

Tags: html, css, flexbox, footer, sticky

So I have been searching everywhere for different solutions to this issue, and I am now not sure whether it is the way I have written out my HTML. I am using PHP to include the navigation file and the footer file into all other files, on the index.php page (Homepage), the sticky footer works and stays at the bottom of the page regardless of content, however every other page, the footer is at the bottom but when content is added, it remains in the same place and just covers the content instead of getting pushed down.

Header HTML

```
<?php echo '

   <html>

    <head>

        <script src="/*/*/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

        <script src="/*/*/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <link href="/*/*/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <link href="/*/*/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <link href="css/media.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amaranth" rel="stylesheet">

        <title> * </title>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="wholeNav">

        <div class="navBar">

            <a href="#video" class="navLinks" id="videoLink">Videos</a>

        </div>

        <div class="navBar">

            <h2 class="headerMain"><a id="pageTitle" href="index.php">*</a></h2>

        </div>

        <div class="navBar">

            <a href="#photo" class="navLinks" id="blogLink">Photos</a>

        </div>

        <div id="leftNav" class="socialNav">

            <a href="#" class="socialMediaLink" id="insta">Instagram <span class="displayNoneMobile">nameHere</span></a>

        </div>

        <div id="middleNav" class="socialNav">

            <a href="#" class="socialMediaLink" id="youTube">YouTube <span class="displayNoneMobile">nameHere</span></a>

        </div>

        <div id="rightNav" class="socialNav">

            <a href="#" class="socialMediaLink" id="twitter">Twitter <span class="displayNoneMobile">nameHere</span></a>

        </div>

    </div>



    </body>

</html>
';?>
```

Footer HTML

```
<?php include 'headnav.php' ;?>

     <?php echo '

      <div id="footer">

    <div class="footerInfo topTwo">

        <a href="about.php" class="footerLinks">About</a>

    </div>

    <div class="footerInfo topTwo">

        <a href="legal.php" class="footerLinks">Legal</a>

    </div>

    <div class="footerInfo bottomFour">

        <a href="contact.php" class="footerLinks">Contact</a>

    </div>

    <div class="footerInfo bottomFour">

        <a href="#" class="footerLinks">Instagram</a>

    </div>

    <div class="footerInfo bottomFour">

        <a href="#" class="footerLinks">YouTube</a>

    </div>

    <div class="footerInfo bottomFour">

        <a href="#" class="footerLinks">Twitter</a>

    </div>

    <div id="copyrightInfo">

    <p>&copy; All Content Owned By * - Website Designed By *</p>

    </div>

</div>

 ';?>
```

Other Page HTML

```
<?php include 'headnav.php' ;?>

<div id="container">

<div class="headerDiv">

    <h3 class="headerMainTwo">Terms &amp; Conditions</h3>

</div>

<div class="infoBox">

    <p class="legalTerms">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque. Donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non. Quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce. Luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus.
    </p>

</div>

<?php include 'footer.php' ;?>  

</div>
```

Footer CSS

```
html{
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100% !important;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Amaranth', sans-serif !important;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#footer{
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #d8445e;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Other Page CSS

```
.headerDiv{
  margin-top: 15vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #d8445e;
  height: 10vh;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #FFF;
  border-top: 2px solid #FFF;
}

.infoBox{
  margin-left: 15%;
  width: 67.7vw;
  height: 50vh;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 28vh;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this, I understand it may be a duplicate post however I have looked at so many posts about this issue and none of those fixes seemed to help my site, so thought it best to ask myself.

Comment: Can you provide css of your Other Page? because for code you provided its working for me

Comment: @nidhi I have updated the question to include the css from the other page

Comment: Mixin Flexbox and position absolute is not gonna work properly. Post a _working_ code snippet that reproduce the issue you describe, not only HTML/CSS fragments

Comment: OT, but there is little sense in outputting large static HTML parts using PHP echo statements. http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php